# ES6 class and extends build-in Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

i try extend Buffer Object in Nodejs

```
TypeError: Buffer2.from(...).slice2 is not a function
```

but it looks like i never can't overwite with new class

How can i make Buffer2.from return Buffer2?

ES6 class and extends keywords

anyway better way without make a fully new class ?

```
class Buffer2 extends Buffer
{

    constructor(obj, encoding)
    {
        console.log('Buffer2::constructor');

        super(obj, encoding);

        return this;
    }

    slice(start, end)
    {
        console.log('Buffer2::slice');

        return this.slice(start, end)
    }

    slice2(start, length)
    {
        console.log('Buffer2::slice2');

        return this.slice(start, start + length)
    }

    static from(obj, encoding)
    {
        console.log('Buffer2::from');

        return new Buffer2(obj, encoding);
    }
}

Buffer2.prototype.slice = function (start, end)
{
    console.log('Buffer2::slice');

    return this.slice(start, end)
}

Buffer2.prototype.slice2 = function (start, length)
{
    return this.slice(start, start + length)
}

console.log(Buffer2, Buffer2.from('7E1D2C', 'hex').slice2(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffer is exported as a function, not as class, here you can see source code [buffer.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js). So, you try to use ES6 class inheritance not to es6 class, but to function. If you want to extend native module - use prototype inheritance. But my advice is to use composition insead of inheritance when you try do add some features to native modules.